# Is this HDMI Cable Male to Male?

Tags: hdmi

I am trying to get accessories for Raspberry Pi.

As stated in the buying guide: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=4277

> If you have a monitor or TV that supports HDMI, then you can grab an
>   HDMI cable

So is male-to-male acceptable?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: In the FAQ, it says the question must relate to a computer, not just to a mobile device.  I think that is why they closed the question.  Too bad the folks didn't say just why they closed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your TV will always have a female connector, so you'll need a male cable.

Since the *Raspberry Pi* also has a female connector, the other end of the cable will also be male.

Then a male-male cable is required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The male to male HDMI is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
So is male-to-male acceptable?
```

This is the only type of HDMI cable really sold.  Any cable that had a female connector would simply extend the length of a male to male cable.

You need to determine if the HDMI connector on the Raspberry Pi is a normal HDMI or a mini-HDMI connection ( there is a size difference ).

> The raspberry pi only supports up to HDMI version 1.3a.  You can use any version HDMI >cable and it will work, but if you buy a lower version (1.2, 1.3, 1.1) there might be >some quality you miss out on and if you buy a higher version (1.4) then you’ll end up >paying for features the Raspberry Pi can’t support.

Just purchase a generic 1.3a+ cable you can get one on Amazon for less then $15.

> *Note* HDMI cables are now called "Standard" and "High Speed".  If you just want >something to connect to your TV/Monitor than get the "Standard" HDMI cable.  It will >still give you a great picture (720p/1080i) and digital audio.  If, however, you're >hoping to use your Raspberry Pi as a media center, you'll probably find it worth while to >go ahead and get the "High Speed" one (it does full 1080p).

Just purchase a generic cable like this one:

[AmazonBasics High-Speed HDMI Cable (9.8 Feet/3.0 Meters) - Supports Ethernet, 3D, and Audio Return [Newest Standard]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003L1ZYYW)

I understand the cable I linked to supports the HDMI 1.4 standard I did that on purpose.  The cable itself is less then $10 in a normal brick and motar store it would cost at least $25.  You can use other vendors besides Amazon but the line of products I linked to is VERY good.

Answer (score 0):

Male to Male is what you want. Just remember to get the right version

Quoted from your article:

> The raspberry pi only supports up to HDMI version 1.3a.

Comment: This only means that the RPi doesn't do Ethernet-over-HDMI; it can still *use* 1.4 cables, just not *fully*.